# Javascript lagging for touchpad when changing css on scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I wrote something like

```
$element.on "scroll", (e) ->
    top = $element[0].scrollTop
    left = $element[0].scrollLeft
    categoryLabelsInner.style.top = -top + 'px'
    monthLabelsInner.style.left = -left + 'px'
```

It works fine if I scroll using my mouse, however there's a significant lagging effect if I'm using touchpad in my 13' macbook.

What's more, if I add the following code:

```
$element.on "mousewheel", (e) -> return
```

Then it works fine for touchpad. Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't look like JavaScript to me.